# Why does case when with a var work without selecting from a table, but not with a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can make it work without the 'From tablename' just fine, but I don't understand my results are blank when I put the table name in there.

This works:

```
    Declare 
        @ThemeId int,

    Set @ThemeId = 1; 

    Select (case  when @ThemeId is not null then @ThemeId
            else '' end) as 'ThemeId'
```

This does not:

```
Declare 
        @ThemeId int,

    Set @ThemeId = 1; 

    Select (case  when @ThemeId is not null then @ThemeId
            else pref.ThemeId end) as 'ThemeId'
            From iReportUserPreference pref
```

I can make the top work how i need it to with some trickery, but I was wondering why the second set does not work.

Comment: Neither one worked for me. You got a syntax error in the `DECLARE` statement. Remove the comma and everything is fine.

Comment: Please define "not work".  Generates an error?  If so, which one?  Returns unexpected results?  If so, how?

Comment: This simple condition can be reduced to IsNull(@ThemeId, pref.ThemeId) or Coalesce(@ThemeId, pref.ThemeId).

Comment: At a guess (since there's not enough information here), `iReportUserPreference` is empty (or there's a `WHERE` you've not shown that filters the results down to 0). A `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause will always have one implicit row, whereas a `SELECT` with a `FROM` clause has exactly as many rows as the combination of `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` produce, which can include 0 rows.

Comment: It gives an empty set even when the variable is set when I include the table. It gives the variable value when no table is included. I get the same result when I use Coalesce.

Comment: Ok, my table is empty... all the values are null so it should be pulling the theme's value of 1, but its still pulling the themeid from the table. Why is this and how can i fix it? I need it to pull the variable value first.

Comment: Makes no sense.  Table is empty but it is pulling themid from table.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just returning zero rows?  Add some more columns.

Comment: You will not believe what it was. There was a foreign key constraint on themeid, but the themes table had no data. It was violating this constraint, but not telling me - just giving me an empty set.

Comment: I believe that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since your case statement has nothing to do with your table, the `FROM` is not required.  Without additional table related information like additional fields or a `WHERE` clause your second query will return the result of your case statement once for each row in your table and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and if it doesn't work, then I think the column "ThemeID" doesn't exist in your table

```
DECLARE @ThemeId INT
SET @ThemeId = 1; 

SELECT ISNULL(@ThemeId,pref.ThemeID) AS ThemeID
From iReportUserPreference AS pref
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are not just returning zero rows?

Include additional columns and test.